# HELM UPGRADE ISSUE: spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "NAME"

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, upgrade, kubernetes-helm

I have been trying to create a POD with HELM UPGRADE:

```
helm upgrade --values=$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/_NAME-deploy-CI/drop/values-NAME.yaml --namespace sda-NAME-pro --install --reset-values --debug --wait NAME .
```

but running into below error:

```
2020-07-08T12:51:28.0678161Z upgrade.go:367: [debug] warning: Upgrade "NAME" failed: failed to create resource: Deployment.apps "NAME" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.volumes[1].secret.secretName: Required value, spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "secretvol"]

2020-07-08T12:51:28.0899772Z Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: Deployment.apps "NAME" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.volumes[1].secret.secretName: Required value, spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "secretvol"]
```

YML part

```
          volumeMounts:
            - name: secretvol
              mountPath: "/etc/secret-vol"
              readOnly: true                     
      volumes:  
        - name: jks
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .Values.secret.jks }}
        - name: secretvol
          secret:
            secretName: {{ .Values.secret.secretvol }}
```

Maybe, the first deploy need another command the first time? how can I specify these value to test it?

Comment: is there a secret with name `secretvol`?

Comment: YML added on the main post. Maybe, I need the same folder in local?

Comment: I reproduced your example and stumbled upon the same issue. The issue showed where there was no value for this variable: `{{ .Values.secret.secretvol }}`. Please check if this variable has a value in the `values.yaml` or in other file that you store your variables. Please let me know if it helped.

Comment: Thanks Dawid!
the part of the YML is a part of another YML, not the values.yml. I suppose these YML is vinculated to values.yaml...but...how can I declare the secret vol" on values.yaml? Do you have any example?

Comment: @RCat, sure I will give you an example for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR**

The issue you've encountered:

```sh
2020-07-08T12:51:28.0899772Z Error: UPGRADE FAILED: failed to create resource: Deployment.apps "NAME" is invalid: [spec.template.spec.volumes[1].secret.secretName: Required value, spec.template.spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[2].name: Not found: "secretvol"]
```

is connected with the fact that the variable: `{{ .Values.secret.secretvol }}` is **missing**.

To fix it you will need to set this value in either:

- Helm command that you are using
- File that stores your values in the Helm's chart.

> ### A tip!
>
> You can run your Helm command with `--debug --dry-run` to output generated `YAML`'s. This should show you where the errors could be located.

There is an official documentation about values in Helm. Please take a look here:

- *[Helm.sh: Docs: Chart template guid: Values files](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/values_files/)*

---

Basing on

> I have been trying to create a POD with HELM UPGRADE:

I've made an example basing on your issue and how you can fix it.

Steps:

- Create a helm chart with correct values
- Edit the values to reproduce the error

### Create a helm chart

For the simplicity of the setup I created basic Helm chart.

Below is the structure of files and directories:

```sh
❯ tree helm-dir
helm-dir
├── Chart.yaml
├── templates
│   └── pod.yaml
└── values.yaml

1 directory, 3 files
```

#### Create `Chart.yaml` file

Below is the `Chart.yaml` file:

```yaml
apiVersion: v2
name: helm-pod
description: A Helm chart for spawning pod with volumeMount
version: 0.1.0
```

#### Create a `values.yaml` file

Below is the simple `values.yaml` file which will be used by **default** in the `$ helm install` command

```yaml
usedImage: ubuntu
confidentialName: secret-password # name of the secret in Kubernetes
```

#### Create a template for a `pod`

This template is stored in `templates` directory with a name `pod.yaml`

Below `YAML` definition will be a template for spawned pod:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name:  {{ .Values.usedImage }} # value from "values.yaml"
  labels:
    app:  {{ .Values.usedImage }} # value from "values.yaml"
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: {{ .Values.usedImage }} # value from "values.yaml" 
    image: {{ .Values.usedImage }}  # value from "values.yaml" 
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: 
    - sleep 
    - infinity
    volumeMounts:
      - name: secretvol # same name as in spec.volumes.name
        mountPath: "/etc/secret-vol"
        readOnly: true       
  volumes: 
  - name: secretvol # same name as in spec.containers.volumeMounts.name
    secret:
      secretName: {{ .Values.confidentialName }} # value from "values.yaml"
```

With above example you should be able to run `$ helm install --name test-pod .`

You should get output similar to this:

```sh
NAME:   test-pod
LAST DEPLOYED: Thu Jul  9 14:47:46 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: DEPLOYED

RESOURCES:
==> v1/Pod
NAME    READY  STATUS             RESTARTS  AGE
ubuntu  0/1    ContainerCreating  0         0s
```

> Disclaimer!
> The ubuntu pod is in the `ContainerCreating` state as there is no [secret](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) named `secret-password` in the cluster.

You can get more information about your pods by running:

- `$ kubectl describe pod POD_NAME`

### Edit the values to reproduce the error

The error you got as described earlier is most probably connected with the fact that the value: `{{ .Values.secret.secretvol }}` was **missing**.

If you were to edit the `values.yaml` file to:

```yaml
usedImage: ubuntu
# confidentialName: secret-password # name of the secret in Kubernetes
```

**Notice the added `#`**.

You should get below error when trying to deploy this chart:

```sh
Error: release test-pod failed: Pod "ubuntu" is invalid: [spec.volumes[0].secret.secretName: Required value, spec.containers[0].volumeMounts[0].name: Not found: "secretvol"]
```

I previously mentioned the `--debug --dry-run` parameters for Helm.

If you run:

- `$ helm install --name test-pod --debug --dry-run .`

You should get the output similar to this (this is only the part):

```yaml
---
# Source: helm-pod/templates/pod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name:  ubuntu # value from "values.yaml"
  labels:
    app:  ubuntu # value from "values.yaml"
spec:
  restartPolicy: Never
  containers:
  - name: ubuntu # value from "values.yaml" 
    image: ubuntu  # value from "values.yaml" 
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: 
    - sleep 
    - infinity
    volumeMounts:
      - name: secretvol # same name as in spec.volumes.name
        mountPath: "/etc/secret-vol"
        readOnly: true       
  volumes: 
  - name: secretvol # same name as in spec.containers.volumeMounts.name
    secret:
      secretName:  # value from "values.yaml"
```

As you can see the value of `secretName` was missing. That's the reason above error was showing up.

```yaml
      secretName:  # value from "values.yaml"
```

Comment: thank you Dawik, fixed! check the lastone comment. Thanks for your guidance

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Dawik, here we have the output:

```
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3090526Z LAST DEPLOYED: Fri Jul 10 11:34:25 2020
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3091661Z NAMESPACE: sda-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3092410Z STATUS: pending-upgrade
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3092796Z REVISION: 13
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3093182Z TEST SUITE: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3093781Z USER-SUPPLIED VALUES:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3105880Z affinity: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3106801Z containers:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3107446Z   port: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3108124Z   portName: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3108769Z   protocol: TCP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3109440Z env:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3110613Z   APP_NAME: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3112959Z   JAVA_OPTS_EXT: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=***  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/truststore/jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3115219Z     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3116160Z   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PROFILE: pro
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3116974Z   TZ: Europe/Madrid
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3117647Z   WILY_MOM_PORT: 5001
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3119640Z   spring_application_name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3121048Z   spring_cloud_config_uri: URI
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3122038Z envSecrets: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3122789Z fullnameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3123489Z image:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3124470Z   pullPolicy: Always
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3125908Z   repository: NAME-REPO
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3126955Z imagePullSecrets: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3127675Z ingress:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3128727Z   enabled: ***
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3129509Z livenessProbe: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3130143Z nameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3131148Z nameSpace: sda-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3131820Z nodeSelector: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3132444Z podSecurityContext: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3133135Z readinessProbe: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3133742Z replicaCount: 1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3134636Z resources:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3135362Z   limits:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3135865Z     cpu: 150m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3136404Z     memory: 1444Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3137257Z   requests:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3137851Z     cpu: 100m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3138391Z     memory: 1024Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3138942Z route:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3139486Z   alternateBackends: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3140087Z   annotations: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3140642Z   enabled: true
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3141226Z   fullnameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3142695Z   host:HOST-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3143480Z   labels: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3144217Z   nameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3145137Z   path: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3145637Z   service:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3146439Z     name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3147049Z     targetPort: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3147607Z     weight: 100
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3148121Z   status: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3148623Z   tls:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3149162Z     caCertificate: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3149820Z     certificate: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3150467Z     destinationCACertificate: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3151091Z     enabled: true
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3151847Z     insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3152483Z     key: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3153032Z     termination: edge
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3154104Z   wildcardPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3155687Z secret:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3156714Z   jks: NAME-jks
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3157408Z   jssecacerts: jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3157962Z securityContext: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3158490Z service:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3159127Z   containerPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3159627Z   port: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3160103Z   portName: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3160759Z   targetPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3161219Z   type: ClusterIP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3161694Z serviceAccount:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3162482Z   create: ***
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3162990Z   name: null
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3163451Z tolerations: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3163836Z 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3164534Z COMPUTED VALUES:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3165022Z affinity: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3165474Z containers:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3165931Z   port: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3166382Z   portName: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3166861Z   protocol: TCP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3167284Z env:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3168046Z   APP_NAME: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3169887Z   JAVA_OPTS_EXT: -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=***  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/truststore/jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3175782Z     -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3176587Z   SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PROFILE: pro
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3177184Z   TZ: Europe/Madrid
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3177683Z   WILY_MOM_PORT: 5001
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3178559Z   spring_application_name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3179807Z   spring_cloud_config_uri: https://URL
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3181055Z envSecrets: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3181569Z fullnameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3182077Z image:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3182707Z   pullPolicy: Always
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3184026Z   repository: REPO
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3185001Z imagePullSecrets: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3185461Z ingress:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3186215Z   enabled: ***
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3186709Z livenessProbe: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3187187Z nameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3188416Z nameSpace: sda-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3189008Z nodeSelector: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3189522Z podSecurityContext: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3190056Z readinessProbe: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3190552Z replicaCount: 1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3191030Z resources:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3191686Z   limits:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3192320Z     cpu: 150m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3192819Z     memory: 1444Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3193319Z   requests:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3193797Z     cpu: 100m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3194463Z     memory: 1024Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3194975Z route:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3195470Z   alternateBackends: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3196028Z   enabled: true
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3196556Z   fullnameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3197601Z   host: HOST-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3198314Z   nameOverride: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3198828Z   path: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3199285Z   service:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3200023Z     name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3233791Z     targetPort: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3234697Z     weight: 100
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3235283Z   status: ""
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3235819Z   tls:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3236787Z     enabled: true
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3237479Z     insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3238168Z     termination: edge
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3238800Z   wildcardPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3239421Z secret:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3240502Z   jks: NAME-servers-jks
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3241249Z   jssecacerts: jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3241901Z securityContext: {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3242534Z service:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3243157Z   containerPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3243770Z   port: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3244543Z   portName: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3245190Z   targetPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3245772Z   type: ClusterIP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3246343Z serviceAccount:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3247308Z   create: ***
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3247993Z tolerations: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3248511Z 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3249065Z HOOKS:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3249600Z MANIFEST:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3250504Z ---
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3252176Z # Source: NAME/templates/service.yaml
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3253107Z apiVersion: v1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3253715Z kind: Service
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3254487Z metadata:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3255338Z   name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3256318Z   namespace: sda-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3256883Z   labels:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3257666Z     helm.sh/chart: NAME-1.0.0
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3258533Z     app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3259785Z     app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3260503Z     app.kubernetes.io/version: "latest"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3261383Z     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3261955Z spec:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3262427Z   type: ClusterIP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3263292Z   ports:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3264086Z     - port: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3264659Z       targetPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3265359Z       protocol: TCP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3265900Z       name: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3266361Z   selector:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3267220Z     app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3268298Z     app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3269380Z ---
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3270539Z # Source: NAME/templates/deployment.yaml
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3271606Z apiVersion: apps/v1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3272400Z kind: Deployment
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3273326Z metadata:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3274457Z   name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3275511Z   namespace: sda-NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3276177Z   labels:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3277219Z     helm.sh/chart: NAME-1.0.0
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3278322Z     app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3279447Z     app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3280249Z     app.kubernetes.io/version: "latest"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3281398Z     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3282289Z spec:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3282881Z   replicas: 1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3283505Z   selector:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3284469Z     matchLabels:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3285628Z       app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3286815Z       app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3287549Z   template:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3288192Z     metadata:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3288826Z       labels:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3289909Z         app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3291596Z         app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3292439Z     spec:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3293109Z       serviceAccountName: default
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3293774Z       securityContext:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3294666Z         {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3295217Z       containers:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3296338Z         - name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3297240Z           securityContext:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3297859Z             {}
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3299353Z           image: "REGISTRY-IMAGE"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3300638Z           imagePullPolicy: Always
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3301358Z           ports:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3302491Z             - name: 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3303380Z               containerPort: 8080
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3304479Z               protocol: TCP
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3305325Z           env:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3306418Z             - name: APP_NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3307576Z               value: "NAME"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3308757Z             - name: JAVA_OPTS_EXT
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3311974Z               value: "-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -Dcom.sun.net.ssl.checkRevocation=***  -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/etc/truststore/jssecacerts -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3313760Z             - name: SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_PROFILE
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3314842Z               value: "pro"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3315890Z             - name: TZ
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3316777Z               value: "Europe/Madrid"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3317863Z             - name: WILY_MOM_PORT
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3318485Z               value: "5001"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3319421Z             - name: spring_application_name
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3320679Z               value: "NAME"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3321858Z             - name: spring_cloud_config_uri
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3323093Z               value: "https://config.sda-NAME-pro.svc.cluster.local"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3324190Z           resources:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3324905Z             limits:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3325439Z               cpu: 150m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3325985Z               memory: 1444Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3326739Z             requests:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3327305Z               cpu: 100m
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3327875Z               memory: 1024Mi
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3328436Z           volumeMounts:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3329476Z             - name: jks
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3330147Z               mountPath: "/etc/jks"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3331153Z               readOnly: true   
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3332053Z             - name: jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3332739Z               mountPath: "/etc/truststore"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3333356Z               readOnly: true
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3334402Z             - name: secretvol
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3335565Z               mountPath: "/etc/secret-vol"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3336302Z               readOnly: true                     
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3336935Z       volumes:  
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3338100Z         - name: jks
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3338724Z           secret:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3339946Z             secretName: NAME-servers-jks
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3340817Z         - name: secretvol
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3341347Z           secret:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3341870Z             secretName: 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3342633Z         - name: jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3343444Z           secret:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3344103Z             secretName: jssecacerts
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3344866Z ---
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3345846Z # Source: NAME/templates/route.yaml
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3346641Z apiVersion: route.openshift.io/v1
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3347112Z kind: Route
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3347568Z metadata:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3354831Z   name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3357144Z   labels:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3358020Z     helm.sh/chart: NAME-1.0.0
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3359360Z     app.kubernetes.io/name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3360306Z     app.kubernetes.io/instance: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3361002Z     app.kubernetes.io/version: "latest"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3361888Z     app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3362463Z spec:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3363374Z   host: HOST
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3364364Z   path: 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3364940Z   wildcardPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3365630Z   port:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3366080Z     targetPort: http
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3366496Z   tls:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3367144Z     termination: edge
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3367630Z     insecureEdgeTerminationPolicy: None
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3368072Z   to:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3368572Z     kind: Service
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3369571Z     name: NAME
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3369919Z     weight: 100
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3370115Z status: 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3370287Z   ingress: []
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3370419Z 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3370579Z NOTES:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3370833Z 1. Get the application URL by running these commands:
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3371698Z   export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace sda-NAME -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=NAME,app.kubernetes.io/instance=NAME" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3372278Z   echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:8080 to use your application"
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3373358Z   kubectl --namespace sda-NAME port-forward $POD_NAME 8080:80
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3373586Z 
2020-07-10T11:34:26.3385047Z ##[section]Finishing: Helm Install/Upgrade NAME
```

looks well and don`t show any error...but if make it without --dry-run crash in the same part...
On the other hand, I try it without this volume and secret...and works perfect! I don't understand it.

Thank you for your patience and guidance.

**UPDATE & FIX:**

finally, the problem was in the file values-NAME.yml:

```
secret:
  jks: VALUE
  jssecacerts: VALUE
```

it need the following line in **secret:**

```
  secretvol: VALUE
```